# Word for reciprocal of debt?

Tags: single-word-requests

Merriam Webster defines debt as "a state of owing". Is there a word for "a state of being owed"?

Comment: Part of me wants to say credit (a creditor is one who is owed money) but it's not quite "a state of being owed".

Comment: Depends on the context and associated jargon.  In some cases it might be "asset".

Comment: Could you provide a sample sentence illustrating how you want to use the word? A "debtor" is one who owes and a "creditor" one who is owed. One could perhaps say something like "I am £300 in credit with them" - meaning they owe me £300.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

**Creditor**

noun [ C ] UK ​  /ˈkred.ɪ.tər/ US ​  /ˈkred.ɪ.t̬ɚ/

someone who money is owed to:

*The company couldn't pay its creditors.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/creditor?topic=borrowers-lenders)

Answer (score 0):

The word "debt" is most commonly used to represent the thing that you owe to someone, but can also mean the state of owing things to people. From your question, you are asking about the state.

### In credit

A state of being owed. It can be used to describe a person's state, or the state of an account they hold with an organization.

> Thank you for your payment of $50 following our invoice to you for $30. Your account is now $20 in credit.

[Citizens' Advice Bureau, UK](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/energy/energy-supply/claim-back-credit/claim-back-credit-from-your-energy-supplier/)

### Asset

Assets are a broad group of things that you can derive benefit from, and they include both tangible things like houses and cars, and intangible things like money in bank accounts or shares.

For a business, [debts owed to the business](https://www.fundera.com/blog/debts-owed-to-a-business-are-referred-to-as-what) are known as "accounts receivable", and are one form of assets.

> He made a spreadsheet of his assets at the bank and in his brokerage accounts.

Comment: Multiple answers and lack of any links to citations is not what is expected.

Comment: In normal conversation I think asset would probably only be used to talk about financial instruments, while debt can be used to talk about non-financial goods as well. Maybe it is right, but I have never heard "in credit" used like that.